# iOS Share Extension not working

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I have a share extension allowing users to upload videos directly from other applications (eg. photos). It has a custom view (not SLComposeServiceViewController).

It was working just fine but currently I'm having strange issue that share extension won't showing up without any reason in particular. I tried to breakpoint in the `viewDidLoad` & `viewWillAppear` methods. But non of these methods are called. It seems like nothing happen when I press the app icon in the share sheet.

The only time I'm able to make it work is after cleaning project and run it. Does anybody experience problem like this before? And any suggestion what could be the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody experience problem like this before?

I am, but
without any details of what your code looks like and what are you doing there - it is hard to say what exactly the reason.

What I can say is that you have crash on start, it is not "nothing happen".
The reasons list are just too wide, so shortly:

- check your threads
- check existing of objects
- check potential buggy-spots
- handle correctly subscribing/unsubscribing to events of `NSNotification` Center
- be noticed that after you call `completeRequestReturningItems` and extension is gone, and you trying to share something again, it probably could be not cleaned from memory and can keep some garbage, so take care about this also.
- try to be as efficient in memory usage as possible